# How to let empty arguments survive in command substitutions?

Tags: bash, quoting

I want to call `dialog` à la:

```
dialog --menu Choose: 0 40 10 A '' B '' C ''
```

except `A`, `B` and `C` are the result of a dynamic query, for the sake of this question the latter being `{ echo A; echo B; echo C; }`.

I can get the desired command line seemingly by:

```
{ echo A; echo B; echo C; } | sed -e "s/\$/ ''/;"
```

but:

```
echo $({ echo A; echo B; echo C; } | sed -e "s/\$/ ''/;")
```

and its output:

```
A '' B '' C ''
```

show that the result of the command substitution is only word-split, but `''` isn't interpreted as an empty argument, but passed verbosely to `echo` (and thus, `dialog` wouldn't display no descriptions for the menu items, but literally `''`s).

I can work around this in bash using arrays, but is there a simpler solution I'm missing?

Given

```
$ e() { printf "tag: [$1] item: [$2]"; }
$ e $(echo "A ''")
$ tag: [A] item: ['']
```

How can I change the `$(...)` part, such that the item is `[]` instead of `['']`.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Given `{ echo A; echo B; echo C; }`, I want to execute `dialog --menu Choose: 0 40 10 A '' B '' C ''`.

Comment: *Why* do you want to run that? What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: His problem is, that he wants to pass an empty string to `dialog` using `$(echo '')`, but even though `$(echo '')` "returns" `''`, it is the string `''` and not an empty string.

Comment: @Tim I updated your question with a clarification. If you do not like it, please revert my change.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann No, it sums it up very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `IFS` (internal field separator)

```
$ IFS=, e $(echo "a,,")
tag: [a] item: []
```

Seems to work. Is it nice? I do not know but would give some array magic a try. By the way, you can often use `${parameter/pattern/string}` for substitution instead of calling `sed`. Unfortunately it only operates on a variable, which makes it less usable.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks.  To call `dialog` however, I had to set `IFS` in a separate command (`IFS=, dialog` didn't work).  I ended up with: `SAVEIFS="$IFS"; IFS=,; if ! dialog --menu 'Select an snapshot to mount' 0 40 10 $(sort .snaplist | sed -e 's/$/,,/;' | tr -d \\n); then […]`

Answer (score 2):

Nice question.

I don't know if this qualifies as "simpler" but it has a certain elegance:

```
with-tags() {
  local line
  if read -r line; then with-tags "$@" "$line" ""; else "$@"; fi
}

{ echo A; echo B; echo C; } |
with-tags dialog --menu Choose: 0 40 10
```

It's easily extensible to handle input lines of the form `TAG <optional description>`:

```
with-tag-lines() {
  local tag desc
  if read -r tag desc; then with-tag-lines "$@" "$tag" "$desc"; else "$@"; fi
}

{ echo A with optional description; echo B; echo C; } |
with-tag-lines dialog --menu Choose: 0 40 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cmd="dialog --menu Choose: 0 40 10 "
arg="`echo $({ echo A; echo B; echo C; } | sed -e "s/\$/ ''/;")`"
eval "${cmd}${arg}"
```

But I think that `sed` not required here. You can keep it simple:

```
cmd="dialog --menu Choose: 0 40 10 "
arg="`echo A \'\' B \'\' C \'\'`"
eval "${cmd}${arg}"
```

Comment: If I wouldn't need the `sed`, I wouldn't have a problem :-).  The issue is that `A`, `B` and `C` come from a dynamic query.

Comment: Yep, but you can easy write `A`, `B` and `C` into `arg` string using command substitution.